# Parsing SOAP response using PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, plsql

I am trying to parse a SOAP response using the following code but I am getting a null response. The response contains multiple namespaces and I think that is where I am having the problem. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
declare
  l_xml  xmltype;
begin
  l_xml := xmltype.createXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.cachelan.com/WebAPI/solarvuDataRetrieve.php" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    <ns1:getDataResponse>
                        <return xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                            <item>
                                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">status</key>
                                <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">content</key>
                                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">"SolarVu OM Data Request"
                                "From Mar 1, 2017 To Mar 4, 2017"

                                "Timestamp","Date","Daily Energy(kWh)","Insolation(Wh/m^2)"
                                "1488344400","Mar 1/17","131.064","1,105.750"
                                "1488430800","Mar 2/17","370.576","3,202.750"
                                "1488517200","Mar 3/17","517.566","4,662.500"
                                "1488603600","Mar 4/17","382.626","6,001.750"
                            </value>
                        </item>
                    </return>
                </ns1:getDataResponse>
                </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');

  for i in (SELECT t."key", t."value"
            FROM dual d,
            XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi",
                                   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "SOAP-ENV",
                                   'http://www.cachelan.com/WebAPI/solarvuDataRetrieve.php' as "ns1",
                                   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd",
                                   'http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap' as "ns2",
                                   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' as "SOAP-ENC"), 
                    '/getDataResponse/return/item[*]'
              PASSING l_xml
              COLUMNS 
                 "key"   varchar2(4000) PATH 'key',
                 "value" varchar2(4000) PATH 'value') t)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Key is: '||i."key");
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't prefixing `getDataResponse` with its namespace in the XPath, and you also aren't including the envelope and body tags; so change the XPath to:

```
'/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:getDataResponse/return/item'
```

With just that change your code generates:

```
Key is: status
Key is: content

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I got this working based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I found that problem was in prefixed namespaces like `<ns1:getDataResponse>` and how Oracle XMLType interpret them. I solved it extracting inner node which have no prefixed namespace, based on your example something like this.

```
declare
   l_xml xmltype;
begin
   l_xml := xmltype.createXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.cachelan.com/WebAPI/solarvuDataRetrieve.php" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    <ns1:getDataResponse>
                        <return xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                            <item>
                                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">status</key>
                                <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">content</key>
                                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">"SolarVu OM Data Request"
                                "From Mar 1, 2017 To Mar 4, 2017"

                                "Timestamp","Date","Daily Energy(kWh)","Insolation(Wh/m^2)"
                                "1488344400","Mar 1/17","131.064","1,105.750"
                                "1488430800","Mar 2/17","370.576","3,202.750"
                                "1488517200","Mar 3/17","517.566","4,662.500"
                                "1488603600","Mar 4/17","382.626","6,001.750"
                            </value>
                        </item>
                    </return>
                </ns1:getDataResponse>
                </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');

   --Pay attention here and changes in path parameter at XMLTABLE
   l_xml := l_xml.EXtract('//*/*//return');

   for i in (select t.key, t.value
               from dual d,
                    XMLTABLE('/return/item' PASSING l_xml COLUMNS key
                               varchar2(4000) PATH 'key',
                              value varchar2(4000) PATH 'value') t) loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Key is: ' || i.key);
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip Seyran, I will keep this trick in the bag for next time.

Comment: This seems like a bit of a hack, and won't really work if you need data from multiple return nodes or multiple llayers within one node, particularly if any do have namespaces. And if you do this, the `xmlnamespaces` clause is redundant, since the extracted node doesn't have a namespace prefix.

Comment: @ Alex Poole it has link to namespace type ex. `<key xsi:type="xsd:string">`  and if omit `xmlnamespace` you will got an error.

Comment: I ran your code with the `xmlnamespaces` clause removed and it worked fine. The namespace is on an attribute that isn't being referenced in this case, so I guess it isn't checked?

Comment: Sorry agree @Alex Poole.